# "Select ... into .." statement fails with "table or view does not exist" even though it should not be run

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have the following PL/SQL script that I'm trying to run through SQL*Plus:

```
DECLARE 
   table_exists number;
   sequence_exists number;
   sequence_start number;
BEGIN
   select count(*) into sequence_exists
       from all_sequences
       where sequence_name='DBSEQ';
   select count(*) into table_exists
       from dba_tables
       where table_name='DBTABLE';
   IF sequence_exists = 0 AND table_exists > 0 THEN
       select MAX(ID) + 1 into sequence_start from DBTABLE;
   ELSE
       sequence_start := 1;
   END;
   IF sequence_exists = 0 THEN
       execute immediate 'CREATE SEQUENCE DBSEQ
             start with ' || sequence_start || '
             increment by 1
             nomaxvalue';
   END IF;
END;
```

(this is somewhat minimized, to show the parts that are actually failing).

The problem is that the row

```
select MAX(ID) + 1 into sequence_start from DBTABLE;
```

fails with "PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist", because the table does not exist (and I've already verified that the table_exists variable is actually 0). So basically, the select runs (or at least fails) even though the if-clause does not execute. I've also verified that the if-clause indeed fails by replacing the select with e.g. creating a table, which does not exist after running the script.

I did also try catching exceptions instead, doing something like this:

```
BEGIN
    select MAX(ID) + 1 into sequence_start from DBTABLE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        sequence_start := 1;
END;
```

but that produced the same error.

So, is there anything special with the select statement, that makes it run before anything else? And how should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that Oracle has to compile the block before it can run it.  Part of compiling the block involves resolving all the static references.  If you have a reference to a table that does not exist, the block will fail to compile so it cannot be run.  Your exception handler doesn't do anything because it is a compilation error, not an execution error.

If you want your block to refer to a table that may not exist at the time the block is compiled, you would need to use dynamic SQL.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select max(id) from dbtable'
   INTO sequence_start;
```

That will allow the block to compile successfully since Oracle doesn't need to resolve references in dynamic SQL statements.  If your code tries to execute the dynamic SQL statement when `dbtable` doesn't exist, you'll get a run-time error (which you could catch with an exception handler).

Comment: Excellent answer! I must say, I never really got the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE thing before, but you explained it very well and concisely.